# Indexed file listing in python for scalable file amount

Tags: python, list, indexing

Is there a way to realize a method like `os.listdir(my_dir)` but only for the top file of a directory or even a certain file in a directory (scanning from top to a specified index) without listing every file?

My goal is to analyze data in a growing dataset, but only the newest additions are relevant to analyze. They are sorted based on their creation time, which i obtain via `fname.stat()`. I don't want to get a list of every file each time, since that is not scalable. Can i tell python to stop scanning after a certain index or scan only one file at a specified index?

Comment: I would have thought the "top" file would depend on how the operating system organises its file structure.  Can you explain what reason there is to think they are sorted by creation time?

Comment: @TMBailey bad wording; i apply fname.stat() and then sort them by creation date myself

Comment: If you have control over the growing dataset, another option might be to use a hierarchical directory tree based on creation times.

Comment: I think `pathlib.Path.iterdir()` is an iterator or generator so returns a single item at a time, but they are in arbitrary order, presumably because there's no telling what the operating system / file system might be doing underneath.

Comment: You may also want to use your OS find command - see `os.system` or the `subprocess` module